# GatherBy output with given Shape

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I would like to group items in a binary list according to some property like in the following simple example.

```
l = {0,0,1,1,0,0}   
{a, b} = GatherBy[l, 0 == # &]
```

This example will return a shape error when `l` only contains one type of element though. Is there a way to force the output of a certain shape.

I could use

```
a = Select[l, 0 == # &];
b = Select[l, 1 == # &];
```

but its much slower.

Comment: The order of elements is also not guaranteed.  Why don't you use `GroupBy` instead?  `asc = GroupBy[l, # == 0 &]; Lookup[asc, True, {}]`.  `{}` is the default, in case `True` is not in the association.  Alternatively, `Join[<|True -> {}, False -> {}|>, asc]`, packaged into a function.

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually, your solution (with `True`) is the one which answers best the OP. It is clear that he expects a binary list, and that he tests a "property" that can be very general. You should just post it.

Answer (score 3):

A very readable version is to make a simple `Switch` after you called `GatherBy` that will create the correct output form:

```
myFunc[list_] := With[{res = Gather[list]},
  Switch[res,
   {{0 ..}, {1 ..}}, res,
   {{1 ..}, {0 ..}}, Reverse[res],
   {{0 ..}}, Append[res, {}],
   {{1 ..}}, Prepend[res, {}],
   _,
   $Failed]
  ]

Column[myFunc/@{{0,0}, {1}, {0,1,0}, {1,0,1}}]
(* {{0,0},{}}
   {{},{1}}
   {{0,0},{1}}
   {{0},{1,1}} 
*)
```

Note, that I used only `Gather` for simplicity and that this approach assumes that your list is really binary. Otherwise, the patterns in the `Switch` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not caused by GatherBy, but by your assumption that a list of two elements will be returned.  You should assign the result to a single variable, and then check its length.

Comment: I'm aware of the cause of the error. I just thought there might be a more elegant solution then using one variable, checking the length, if the length was 1 I would have to check which of the two elements i got etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
group[shape_][list_] := 
 GroupBy[list, # &] // (Lookup[#, shape] /. Missing[__] -> {}) &
```

or simpler (as proposed by **@Szabolcs** in the comments) :

```
group[shape_][list_] := GroupBy[list, # &] // Lookup[#, shape, {}] &
```

**Examples**

```
list1 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
list2 = {1, 1, 1};
list3 = {0, 0, 1, 0};
```

then

```
group[{0, 1}][list1]
```

> `{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {}}`

```
group[{0, 1}][list2]
```

> `{{}, {1, 1, 1}}`

```
group[{0, 1}][list3]
```

> `{{0, 0, 0}, {1}}`

```
group[{0, 1, 2, 3}][list2]
```

> `{{}, {1, 1, 1}, {}, {}}`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this when I wrote the comment. `Lookup` takes a third argument for the default.

Comment: @Szabolcs ;) I somehow did not pay attention to this 3rd argument ! I will add this to the post.

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster:

```
reformat[list_] := With[{tot = Total@list}, {
   ConstantArray[1, tot],
   ConstantArray[0, Length@list - tot]
   }]
```